# solrCloud error while uploading the config directory to zookeeper

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4, solrnet

I am using below command to upload the configuration from solr to zookeeper.

solr zk upconfig -n example1 -d conf

I am getting below error , at the same time I see example1 configuration has been added to the zookeeper but solconfig.xml , managed-schema , other synonym files are missing there , any reason why ?

> Uploading D:\solr-7.5.0\bin\conf for config example1 to ZooKeeper at
>   localhost:2181,localhost:2184,localhost:2185 WARN  - 2019-01-02
>   17:06:59.441; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn; Session
>   0x100419a6c9a000b for server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181,
>   unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
>   ~[zookeeper-3.4.11.jar:3.4.11-37e277162d567b55a07d1755f0b31c32e93c01a0]
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
>   ~[zookeeper-3.4.11.jar:3.4.11-37e277162d567b55a07d1755f0b31c32e93c01a0]
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1144)
>   [zookeeper-3.4.11.jar:3.4.11-37e277162d567b55a07d1755f0b31c32e93c01a0]
>   WARN  - 2019-01-02 17:06:59.552;
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Watcher
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@3343041c name:
>   ZooKeeperConnection
>   Watcher:localhost:2181,localhost:2184,localhost:2185 got event
>   WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null path: null type:
>   None

Comment: don't you need to specify -zkhost zookeeper_host ?

Comment: even if we specify it is taking the value of zk_host

Comment: When you configured zookeeper, what are your timeout settings?

Comment: @kellyfj - set ZK_HOST=127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2184,127.0.0.1:2185
set ZK_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=60000

Comment: and tickTime i have increased from 2000 to 20000

Comment: How about syncLimit and initLimit?

Comment: @kellyfj - it was default -initLimit=5 syncLimit=2 , then i also increased them to initLimit=15 syncLimit=20 , but the same error

Comment: All I can think now is Firewall (or perhaps one of the zookeeper nodes has run out of disk/memory). Is there anything in the zookeeper logs?